# How can i merge red green and bleu bitmaps to get the original bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I want to merge the red bitmap the green bitmap and blue bitmap to get the original rgb bitmap can any one know how can i merge them, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

At first, I would say to create a new Bitmap file and to create each pixel by computing green, blue and red ones to get the merged one.